# How to persist these entities without getting duplication exception using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Consider the following:

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name="employee_clients_map",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")})
    private Set<Client> clients;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

-

```
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", unique=true)
    private String name;

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

-

```
// define employees
Employee e1 = new Employee("Jeff");
Employee e2 = new Employee("Matt");

// define clients
Client c1 = new Client("Company123");
Client c2 = new Client("CompanyABC");

// configure employee - client relationships
Set<Client> e1ClientRelationship = new HashSet<>();
Set<Client> e2ClientRelationship = new HashSet<>();

e1ClientRelationship.add(c1);

e2ClientRelationship.add(c1);
e2ClientRelationship.add(c2);

e1.setClients(e1ClientRelationship);
e2.setClients(e2ClientRelationship);

// persist employees
em.persist(e1);
em.persist(e2);
```

Running the above once will work fine. But say I want to add the same clients to a new employee after the clients were persisted like so:

```
Employee e3 = new Employee("Kim");
Set<Client> e3ClientRelationship = new HashSet<>();
e3ClientRelationship.add(new Client("Company123"));

em.persist(e3);
```

I would get this error:

> "Duplicate entry 'Company123' for key 'name_UNIQUE'"

I tried using merge but it will not work because the ids are generated only for inserts. What are some ways to handle this situation? Is JPA not good for this scenario?

I need a solution that work well with persisting a lot of entities at once - the examples I showed are obviously contrived.

Also I am using Eclipselink.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want to add the same client to a new employe so you need to get the existing client and add it instead:

```
String sql = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.name = :name";
TypedQuery<Client> query = EM.createQuery(sql,Client.class);
Client = query.getSingleResult();
Employee e3 = new Employee("Kim");
Set<Client> e3ClientRelationship = new HashSet<>();
e3ClientRelationship.add(client);
EM.persist(e3);
```

It has to be the same EM used for finding and persisting

Comment: This solution is not very effective for persisting a lot of employees. What if I had hundreds of employees and each one had an average of 10 clients. Would I have to loop all the employees and their clients and switch out the non managed clients with managed ones? In addition if I cumulate thousands of clients wouldn't I initially be making thousands of requests if I was persisting a new load of employees that used those clients?

Comment: Yes you would have, but where the clients came in the first place into your employees? If you took them directly from DB you would not have to replace them. As for your second question I did not understood it. You want a relation so you need to know both parts of that relation. If it was simple sql you would still need to know what is the id of your clients to be able to fill the join table, so you would query for theri names. It is as inefficinect as JDBC, you cannot escape it.

Comment: In my application the "clients" won't be loaded from the db. The employee - client relationship is discovered through a third party rest endpoint - that is where my second question is coming from. Basically the equivalent of batch loading for saving is what I think I want.

Comment: Could I just preload all the clients into the entity manager with a single request before switching out the clients? This way em.find isnt making requests to the db

Comment: kind of, you can query for all the clients, and they will be loaded to em. but then you are searching by name not id, so the query will be invoked, and the only saving is the building of the client objects as their will be fetched by their id from DB. You should rather query for all clients in names taken from employee, set the result on the employee.